# Proving probability to a friend about a drop

Tags: probability

This is about an item drop in a game.

So a friend of mine doesn't believe that if a boss has a 1/100 chance to drop a package and then getting an item with 1/25.6 chance from the package is easier than getting the item straight away from the boss with 1/2560 chance. How can I prove this is wrong/right?

Comment: From the software developers point of view it is easier to only have to code one random number check.

Comment: If "easier" is with regard to "likelihood of getting the item": the probability of getting the item in the end is mathematically the same in both cases (disregarding issues with respect to numerical precision and pseudo-random number generation).

Comment: Thanks for answering angryavian. What are the issues regarding numerical precision and pseudo-random number generation? I've never heard of those terms.

Comment: He still doesn't believe me. Now he says that when taking a small sample it should be easier to get it. Is this true?